# Ansible playbook output is coming in stderr block

Tags: shell, ansible

I am trying to run ansible playbook which is running shell module. The module is having a block of commands.

```
- name: Run {{ action }}  to {{ targetenv }}
  shell: |
             cd "{{ env_select[env_param].path }}/Workspace/linuxtest";
             source env/bin/activate;
             export HOME="{{ env_select[env_param].path }}";
             
             developer init "{{ deployment_environment }}" pa na na;
             
             developer deploy manifest all abc_service --key {{ key }} --action {{ action }} --target_env {{ targetenv }};
      when: action == "start" or action == "stop"
```

This is running successfully.
But the playbook output is failing.
The command output "developer deploy manifest all abc_service --key {{ key }} --action {{ action }} --target_env {{ targetenv }};" is coming under "stderr". "stdout" and "stdout_lines" is showing different data.

```
    "stdout": "deployables.all\n{'deployable': ['core_services', 'ui', 'abc_service', 'abc_deploy']}\n0\n0\n0\n0\n0\n0\n0\n0\n0\n0\n0\n0\n0\n0\n0\n0",
    "stdout_lines": [
        "deployables.all",
        "{'deployable': ['core_services', 'ui', 'abc_service', 'abc_deploy']}",
        "0",
        "0",
        "0",
        "0",
        "0",
        "0",
        "0",
        "0",
        "0",
        "0",
        "0",
        "0",
        "0",
        "0",
        "0",
        "0"
    ]
}
```

What is the issue with the play. How can I fix this?

Comment: "_output is coming in `stderr` block_", since you haven't show such, what output is that? "_`stdout` and `stdout_lines` is showing different data_", no, the data is obviosly the same but differently formatted. What kind of command is `developer`? Where is that from? Please take not that not all comands report to `stdout` by default. Maybe you have to redirect via `2>&1`.

Answer (score 0):

- `stdout` contains the normal output of a command
- `stdout_lines` contains the output as a list of strings, each containing one item per line from the original output

Comment: What does the `developer` cli command do?

Comment: we have built our own cli, developer will deploy all the services.

Comment: It is possible that the developer cli reports to stderr by default. Redirect the output to stdout or change it in the developer cli.